# Call the element in a list

Tags: r

```
>str(testdata[1])

 List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   10640 obs. of  13 variables:
   ..$ logprice      : num [1:10640] 12.3 12.1 13.1 14 12.5 ...
   ..$ bedrooms      : int [1:10640] 3 2 3 4 3 3 3 4 3 4 ...
```

I skipped the rest of 11 variables. My question is, how to call out the "logprice" in this data set,
`testdata[1]$logprice` doesn't work

Comment: `testdata[[1]]$logprice`?

Comment: Oh my god, your right. That's a stupid mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general, when working with lists `[[]]` returns a single element, whereas `[]` returns a list of elements. So when you try `testdata[1]` you're actually still returning a list (of one element) so you can't access what you want using `$`.

Mike H provided this solution as a comment, and Calum You was right in linking to [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis) if you want to understand the nuances a bit more.

Between all that hopefully the mistake isn't just obvious, but the explanation for it is too!

`testdata[[1]]$logprice`